# Applying the Decorator Pattern to Forms

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I'm trying to apply the Decorator Design Pattern to the following situation:

I've 3 different kind of forms: Green, Yellow, Red.

Now, each of those forms can have different set of attributes. They can have a minimize box disabled, a maximized box disabled and they can be always on top.

I tried to model this the following way:

```
              Form <---------------------------------------FormDecorator
              /\                                                  /\
     |---------|-----------|               |----------------------|-----------------|
GreenForm  YellowForm   RedForm  MinimizeButtonDisabled MaximizedButtonDisabled AlwaysOnTop
```

Here is my GreenForm code:

```
public class GreenForm : Form {
    public GreenForm() {
        this.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
    }

    public override sealed Color BackColor {
        get { return base.BackColor; }
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }
}
```

FormDecorator:

```
public abstract class FormDecorator : Form {
    private Form _decoratorForm;

    protected FormDecorator(Form decoratorForm) {
        this._decoratorForm = decoratorForm;
    }
}
```

and finally NoMaximizeDecorator:

```
public class NoMaximizeDecorator : FormDecorator
{
    public NoMaximizeDecorator(Form decoratorForm) : base(decoratorForm) {
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
    }
}
```

So here is the running code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(CreateForm());
}

static Form CreateForm() {
    Form form = new GreenForm();
    form = new NoMaximizeDecorator(form);
    form = new NoMinimizeDecorator(form);

    return form;
}
```

The problem is that I get a form that isn't green and that still allows me to maximize it. It is only taking in consideration the NoMinimizeDecorator form. I do comprehend why this happens but I'm having trouble understanding how to make this work with this Pattern.

I know probably there are better ways of achieving what I want. I made this example as an attempt to apply the Decorator Pattern to something. Maybe this wasn't the best pattern I could have used(if one, at all) to this kind of scenario. Is there any other pattern more suitable than the Decorator to accomplish this? Am I doing something wrong when trying to implement the Decorator Pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not actually implementing the decorator pattern.  For a proper implementation of the pattern, you need to subclass `Form` to create your decorator, and then intercept all operations taken on your decorator and forward them to your private `Form` instance.  You sort of do that, except that aside from assigning a reference in the `FormDecorator` constructor, you never again use that private `Form` instance.  The net result is that you create a `GreenForm`, then wrap it in a `NoMaximizeDecorator`, and then you wrap that in a `NoMinimizeDecorator`.  But because you never forward operations taken against the `NoMinimizeDecorator` to the wrapped `Form` instance, only the `NoMinimizeDecorator` instance actually applies any behavior to the instance that's used.  This fits with what you observe when you run your code: a standard window with a disabled Minimize button.

`Form` is a really bad example for creating decorators in C#, because most of its properties and methods are non-virtual, meaning if you're accessing the decorated form via a `Form` reference, you have no way to intercept the base class's properties - you can't effectively "wrap" `Form`.

**EDIT**

It occurs to me that the statement "Form is a really bad example for creating decorators in C#" really begs the question of what *is* a good example.  Typically, you'll use the decorator pattern to provide a custom interface implementation without implementing the *entire* implementation from scratch.  A **very** common example is generic collections.  Most everything that wants list functionality doesn't depend on, e.g., `List<String>`, but rather on `IList<String>`.  So, if you for example want a custom collection that won't accept strings shorter than 5 characters, you would use something like the following:

```
public class MinLengthList : IList<String>
{
    private IList<string> _list;
    private int _minLength;

    public MinLengthList(int min_length, IList<String> inner_list)
    {
        _list = inner_list;
        _minLength = min_length;
    }

    protected virtual void ValidateLength(String item)
    {
        if (item.Length < _minLength)
            throw new ArgumentException("Item is too short");
    }

    #region IList<string> Members

    public int IndexOf(string item)
    {
        return _list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, string item)
    {
        ValidateLength(item);
        _list.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _list.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _list[index];
        }
        set
        {
            ValidateLength(value);
            _list[index] = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<string> Members

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        ValidateLength(item);
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(string item)
    {
        return _list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(string[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _list.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return _list.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(string item)
    {
        return _list.Remove(item);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<string> Members

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)_list).GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        IList<String> custom_list = new MinLengthList(5, new List<String>());
        custom_list.Add("hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a misapplication of the decorator pattern.  The decorator pattern is concerned with the behavior of objects.  You're *constructing* objects which falls under the creational umbrella.  While you might be able to wrap your head around "not having a maximize button" being a behavior it sounds a little off kilter.

I don't think there's a real way to fix your design though.  The decorator pattern just doesn't fit.  Any attempt to fix this up is just going to be incredibly crufty when you could just use a Builder.

What I *could* see doing is decorating the *Builder* of a form to perform these actions while building.  It would look something like this...

```
public interface IFormBuilder {
    public Form BuildForm();   
}

public class FormBuilder : IFormBuilder {
   public Form BuildForm(){
        return new Form();
   }
}

public class NoMaximizeFormBuilder : IFormBuilder {
    private IFormBuilder _builder;
    public NoMaximizeFormBuilder (IFormBuilder builder){
        _builder = builder;             
    }
    public Form BuildForm(){
        f = _builder.BuildForm();
        f.MaximizeBox = false;
        return f;
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this...

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(CreateForm());
}

static Form CreateForm() {

    var b = new FormBuilder();
    var b = new NoMaximizeFormBuilder(b);
    return b.Build();
}
```

But even that is a little ugly.   You might be able to transform this into a fluent interface for building forms.

Answer (score 0):

try to make your pattern to apply the decorator properties to the same object, not creating new Forms:

```
public abstract class FormDecorator {
    protected Form _decoratorForm;

    protected FormDecorator(Form decoratorForm) {
        this._decoratorForm = decoratorForm;
    }
    public abstract void Decorate();
}

public class NoMaximizeDecorator : FormDecorator
{
    public NoMaximizeDecorator(Form decoratorForm) : base(decoratorForm) {
         Decorate();
    }
    public override void Decorate() {
        _decoratorForm.MaximizeBox = false;
    }
}
```

And in your Main:

```
static Form CreateForm() {
    Form form = new GreenForm();
    new NoMaximizeDecorator(form);
    new NoMinimizeDecorator(form);

    return form;
}
```

Comment: The decorator pattern doesn't look like this. The decorator class hierarchy must inherit the base class of the decorated class hierarchy. The abstract FormDecorator is supposed to define a default behaviour for all the base class methods.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like this. It does what it's supposed, though.